# log4net CSV File Appender Custom Parameters

Tags: csv, log4net, appender

I am currently using log4net for an application I am working on. I have setup a CsvRollingFileAppender but am wonder how I can extend it to log passed parameters. An example would be something along the lines of the following:

```
log.Info(string.format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}", value1, value2, value3, value4));
```

The config for my Appender looks like this

```
<appender name="CsvRollingFileAppender" type="DataCalcuation.Classes.CsvHeaderOverride">
  <threshold value="INFO" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="logs/" />
  <datePattern value="'DataCaclulation'.MM.dd.yyyy'.csv'" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <header value="DateTime,Level,Location,Message&#13;&#10;" />
    <conversionPattern value="%date{M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff},%level,%location,%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I would like to have it setup to have the headers of

```
 DateTime, Level, Location, PassedValue1, PassedValue2,  .....
```

I have stumbled across a few different articles like the following and wondered if that was the correct approach or if there was a more efficient way

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

I think I have to do something like this
 - [Mapping message properties to CSV columns using log4net](http://element533.blogspot.in/2010/05/mapping-message-object-properties-to.html)

Answer:

As promised here is the code I used to achieve what I was looking to do all credit goes to Steven Padfield whose post I used

I created a class called CsvLogEvent with the items I wanted to capture in the log

```
public class CsvLogEvent
{
     public int Value1 {get; set;}
     public string Value2 {get; set;}
     public string Value3 {get; set;}
     public int Value4 {get; set;} 
}
```

I then used the following format to log the events

```
private readonly ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

log.Info(new CsvLogEvent {
     Value1 = 1,
     Value2 = "Test",
     Value3 = "Log Event",
     Value4 = 0
});
```

To property format the CSV output I had to create a class to handle the new Pattern

```
public class CsvPattern : PatternLayout
{
     public override void Format(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
     {
          if (loggingEvent.MessageObject != null)
          {
               PropertyInfo[] properties = loggingEvent.MessageObject.GetType().GetProperties();
               foreach(PropertyInfo prop in properties)
               {
                    object value = prop.GetValue(loggingEvent.MessageObject, null);
                    loggingEvent.Properties[prop.Name] = value;
               }
           }
           base.Format(writer, loggingEvent);
     }
}
```

Then finally setup the appender in your app.config file

```
<appender name="Test" type="DataCalcuation.Classes.CsvAppender">
  <threshold value="INFO" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="logs/" />
  <datePattern value="'DataCaclulation'.MM.dd.yyyy'.csv'" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="DataCalcuation.Classes.CsvPattern">
    <header value="DateTime,Level,Location,Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4&#13;&#10;" />
    <conversionPattern value="%date{M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff},%level,%location,%property{Value1},%property{Value2},%property{Value3},%property{Value4}%newline" />        
  </layout>
</appender>
```

- [Adding custom parameters to the log](https://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/adding-custom-parameters-to-the-log/)
- [Log4Net Custom Appender](http://jonhilton.net/2008/07/23/log4net-custom-appender/)

Comment: Are you facing any problem using mentioned approach? What's the question?

Comment: Not facing any current problems just started on the mentioned methods just wanted to make sure I was on the correct path to achieve what I wanted

Comment: @ondrovic I know that is a long time ago, but is it possible that you can provide the DataCalcuation.Classes.CsvPattern set up? Thank you in advance or you can explain more details if you remembering the implementation